# Converting days to months of the year

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series, linegraph

I have a data frame with one of the columns given as time. The time column is as a result of simulations from ODE system of equations. I want to convert the time column to months of the year.

```
df <- data.frame(time = c(1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100), 
                 population = c(100, 200, 250, 320, 410, 400, 380, 365, 300, 275, 215))

ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=population))+
  geom_line()
```

This produces a time series plot with time in the x-axis as numbers from 1 to 100. I want this time to be changed to months starting from January.

Comment: You should clarify: what unit is `time` in? Is that months?, such that t=1 is January and t=10 is October of the same year, and t=20 is August of the subsequent year, etc?

Comment: @langtang you skipped over the Differential Equation part

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion in the question. Time is in days and population is just numbers. And so the task is how do I convert time in days to months. I hope this clarifies it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert your time to month number and use `scale_x_continuous` with `month.name` to get the right `breaks` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(num_month = round(time/30.417) + 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=num_month, y=population)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(month.name), labels = month.name)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

month.abb give the abbreviated month label from a numerical month 1=Jan, 2=Feb...

If time is in days:

```
days = c(1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,500,600,1000)
months <- round(days/30.417,0)
month.abb[months %% 12]
```